# C++ << operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

As per Deitel's 9ed C++ How to program, p. 444:

> Why Overloaded Stream Insertion and Stream Extraction Operators Are Overloaded
>   as Non-Member Functions
>
> The overloaded stream insertion operator (<<) is used in an expression in which the left operand has type ostream &, as in cout << classObject. To use the operator in this manner where the right operand is an object of a user-defined class, it must be overloaded as a nonmember function. To be a member function, operator << would have to be a member of class ostream. This is not possible for user-defined classes, since we are not allowed to modify C++ Standard Library classes.

The thing is << is already a member of ostream.  What exactly is it talking about?  Am I missing something?

=================================================================

OK, looking back to p. 440:

> Overloaded operator functions for binary operators can be member functions only when the left operand is an object of the class in which the function is a member.

And `<<` is already a member of `ostream`, and since redefinition of C++ STL classes is not allowed, `<<` must be overloaded as a non-member function.  In short, the wording in Deitel's is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

For a user-defined class you cannot add another overloaded member function `operator<<()` into `ostream`. Thus you must use the non-member function style of operator overloading to support the user defined class.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyClass& rhs);
```

Comment: If I define an overload for `operator<<()` in my own class, it is pushed into `ostream` too?  I thought it was kept for the class only.  Can you clarify?

Comment: No, your overload is not pushed into `ostream`. In my answer the function `operator<<()` does _not_ belong to any class.